# Suggestions for a leash reactive dog who reacts to random people

Tags: aggression, leash-training, reactivity

Does anyone have any suggestions for helping my dog get over her leash reactivity towards people? My newly adopted rescue dog gets triggered by dogs and people on walks. We've been working on this for a couple months, and she's slowly getting better about dogs (she can almost always handle them across the street now) but seems to be getting worse about people.

The thing is, she's fine with about 95% of people, and then will randomly get stiff at random people. If she were just reactive towards people with hats, or elderly asian folks or bald men or something, it would be easy...get her around a bunch of those folks, and show her they're good. However, it seems completely unpredictable who she'll react to. She reacts to people equally across all genders, colors and atire. She's a bit more reactive near our apartment, but other than that there's no discernible pattern. I fear my strategy of asking her to sit, sweet talking her and giving her treats when a person approaches might actually be contributing to her people reactivity since because I can't find a pattern, I do this for all people, even though she likely won't react to them.

Any ideas for helping my dog who's only reactive to occasional random people?

EDIT: By reactive towards people/dogs I mean:While I'm holding the leash and walking her posture will stiffen. She then lunges at them barking loudly and without pause. When her posture stiffens she'll stop responding to my 'look' command that she follows very well when not triggered. She'll sometimes sit if i ask her while she's lunging and barking, but she'll still bark aggressively

Comment: Welcome to Pets SE. Can you explain how she is behaving at which times? Leash pulling? Growling? etc...